# How To get the FromEmail,FromName in Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

How To get the FromEmail,FromName in Exacttarget using query Acitivity or Anything

Answer (score 1):

These can be gathered from the [Job Dataview](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/) using a [Query Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

The fields you would need to pull are 'FromName' and 'FromEmail'.

Comment: How to get Reply Emails in Exacttarget

Comment: That is much more difficult to get - best you can get from a query is via Send Classification.  If you want to get more exposure to this need, I would create a new question asking - I would recommend providing some background on what you have tried already and provide relevance and existing code where applicable.